# Can use Array_sum or loop and make sum?

Tags: php, arrays

Have an array

```
array(array('a'=>'s','add'=>1),
      array('a'=>'s1','add'=>2),
      array('a'=>'s2','add'=>3)
      ...
      ...
     );
```

I want to sum of all key `add` together.so result should be `6`

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If really only the one column in the subarrays contains numeric values, then you could get away with `$sum = array_sum(array_map("array_sum", $array))` - otherwise manual loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `array_sum` only works on single-dimensional arrays. Since you're working with an array of associative arrays, you're going to have to approach it differently. If you know your array will have the same form as the one you've linked above, you can simply use something like this:

```
$total = 0;
foreach( $arrs as $arr )
{
    $total += $arr['add'];
}
echo $total;
```

Where `$arrs` is the array you've defined above.

Answer (score 7):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($yourArray as $element) {
    $sum += $element['add'];
}
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$sum = 0;

foreach($array1 as $array) {
    $sum += $array['add'];
}

echo $sum;  // will echo '6'
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner `echo array_sum(array_column($a, "add"));`